# MVC Post Model is Empty

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc

I'm having a problem with simple form-model binding. The *customCepTelefonu* attribute is null inside viewModel on debugging. However Post seems to sending the correct data with correct format (Checked with the Request method)

What am I missing here?

Controller

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult UpdateEmployee(EmployeeUpdateViewModel viewModel) **In viewModel customCepTelefonu is Empty**
{
    var value = Request["EmployeeUpdateViewModel.customCepTelefonu"]; **With the old way i can get the data**
    ....
}
```

Model;

```
public class EmployeeUpdateViewModel
{
    public int referans { get; set; }
    public string customTelefon { get; set; }
    public string customCepTelefonu { get; set; }
    public string customKisaNumara { get; set; }
    public string customCepKisaNumara { get; set; }
    public DateTime dogumTarihi { get; set; }
    public HttpPostedFileBase ImageUpload { get; set; }
}
```

View;

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("UpdateEmployee", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(p => p.EmployeeUpdateViewModel.customCepTelefonu)

    <button type="submit">Save</button>
}
```

Comment: What is the model in your view (it does not appear to be `EmployeeUpdateViewModel`). They must be the same, or you need to use the `Prefix` property of `BindAttribute`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your @Model in the view is not an `EmployeeUpdateViewModel`.
You need to change the parameter in the `UpdateEmployee` Method to the same type as your `@Model` is.